# Cell will show a value depending on another cell

Tags: excel, if-statement

Good morning everyone

I am new in Excel and need your help. I have search on Google, your site but could not find any help.

I have a drop down menu in the cell B21, depending on the value choosen, the cell B64 will nee to show a result.

My drop down values on cell B21 are

- IA - Industrial
- SA - Special Market
- IC - Industrial X
- SC - Special Market X
- 03 - ZMKT & ZLIT
- 03 - ZDIE

If IA or IC is choosen, I will need a code "1201010" to appear in cell B64
If SA or SC is choosen, I will need a code "1301010" to appear in cell B64
If 03 - ZMKT & ZLIT is choosen I will need the code "1201030" to appear in cell B64
If 03 - ZDIE is choosen I will need the code "1201010" to appear in cell B64

I hope this explanation is good enough :) (sorry I am french speaker)

Thank you for your help

Pierre

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Just a hint - Try `If` with `Or` to build your condition. If you face any issue, SO users can help.

Comment: The problem is that I am very new with excel and do not know how works the formula if etc.. I checked online for about two hours, on several sites, but I have not found anything that looks like what I need....... if someone could help ? that would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this in B64

```
=IF(OR(B21="IA - Industrial", B21="IC - Industrial X"),1201010,
   (IF(OR(B21="SA - Special Market", B21="SC - Special Market X"),1301010,
       (IF(B21="03 - ZMKT & ZLIT",1201030,1201010)))))
```